# Corona SDK: The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, coronasdk, google-play-services, android-sdk-tools

tried to use google game services with corona sdk. In ios version, there is no error or problem. Its good. In android version, it seems like to login(in user interface, user logged in) and the player name's appear on the top of screen but login callback is not working properly.

Debugged production application with adb logcat. Logs are bellow. How can i solve this problem?

The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

```
D/BaseGameActivity( 9998): onCreate: creating GamesClient
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 9998): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
D/BaseGameActivity( 9998): isGooglePlayServicesAvailable returned 0
D/BaseGameActivity( 9998): beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.
D/BaseGameActivity( 9998): Connecting GamesClient.
E/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 9998): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
W/ContextImpl( 9998): Implicit intents with s
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build.settings, do you have the following:

```
-- Android-specific settings
    android =
    {
        versionCode = "1",
        googlePlayGamesAppId = "XXXXXXXXX",
        usesPermissions =
        {
            "android.permission.INTERNET",
        },
    },

plugins =
    {
       ["CoronaProvider.gameNetwork.google"] =
       {
          publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
          supportedPlatforms = { android = true }
       },
    },
```

Comment: sure, its seems like a same configuration except { versionCode = "1", }